# Is it good Idea to have save(), get() and delete() operations in domain object as per DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

This came up while designing domain objects in our application.

If we consider domain objects having domain logic, Can we model save(), delete() or get() in the domain object, so that it indicates that the domain object knows how to save itself, how to delete itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persistence is not domain logic, it's simply a technical concern. The aggregate roots shouldn't be aware of persistence details at all. Read about the Repository pattern. Also, DDD is not so much about tactical patterns. The Ubiquitous Language, Bounded Contexts and Context Maps are the most important aspects of DDD.

Comment: If the domain object save() is doing some business rules check and then delegating the call to dao for e.g.                                                                        Public void save() { if ( validate()) dao.store(this) }

Comment: Business objects should ensure that they aren't put in an invalid state and they do not reference a DAO. Like I said, go read about the repository pattern and application services in the context of DDD.